# Looking for young adult book about an underground city from the 1970's

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, underground-civilization

I think the name of the textbook was "Odyssey". The book was published separately because I found it in the library. Something happened on the surface of the Earth so everyone lived underground. I remember that everyone was hairless. A boy found his way to the surface and found that it was okay to live upon and then he found other humans living there. I think I read it in 1973.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very common theme for YA literature, but there are some widespread classics.

- [City of Ember](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_City_of_Ember) by Jeanne DuPrau, well known and not much to say (except they *do* have hair!)
- [Outside](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/andre-norton/outside/) by Andre Norton, girl escapes domed city and finds she has telepathy
- [Journey Outside](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/mary-q-steele-3/journey-outside/) by Mary Steele, families live on rafts floating on an underground river
- [And All Between](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_All_Between) by Zilpha Snyder, complex story with multiple groups, girl finds she has telekinesis.
- [This Time of Darkness](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/h-m-hoover-2/this-time-of-darkness/) by Helen Mary Hoover, rich people live at the top of the city and can still see the sky. Protagonist meets a boy from the outside.
- [The City Under Ground](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/563737.The_City_Under_Ground) by Suzanne Martel, the city of Surreal finds there is another city stealing their electricity
- [Dark Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Universe_%28novel%29) by Daniel Galouye, basically Quest for Light.

I seem to recall one of these re-does the [Allegory of the Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_Cave), which I mention simply because you noted something about Odyssey.

Comment: 'Devil on my Back' by Monica Hughes?

Comment: sounds like The City Under Ground cf this cover: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51uKy3nZDsL.jpg

Comment: @AaronGullison - indeed, I think you've nailed it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was the book by Suzanne Martel I was looking for. I kept typing in the word "underground", instead it was broken up to under and ground. Was able to find a copy through Mel.org at Central Michigan University. The book is so fragile but I read it carefully.

Answer (score 3):

The book is called "The City Under Ground" by Suzanne Martel published in 1964. Thank you Maury Markowitz for your help in finding this book. I also found it by combing through different book lists on Goodreads.